# Angularjs select display value if not in array

Tags: angularjs, arrays, select, ng-show

I would like to create a select for add and remove value in my array. But the value must be unique.

This is my code but dosen't work correctly because I don't know how I can to hide or show the value in the select

```
  <div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="myController">
        <p>Select something</p>
    <select ng-model="selectedBucket" 
     ng-options="row as row.display for row in bucketEnum | filter:bootstrapValues">
    </select>

    <button ng-click="add(selectedBucket.value)">
    add
    </button>

        <br>
        {{initialSet}}
         <br>
        {{bucketEnum}}
    </div>
</div>
```

And controller and filters :

```
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.controller('myController', function ($scope, $filter) {
         $scope.initialSet = [1, 2, 4, 7];
         $scope.bucketEnum = [
            { display: '0', value: 0, bool:true },
            { display: '1', value: 1, bool:true},
            { display: '2', value: 2, bool:true },
            { display: '3', value: 3, bool:true },
            { display: '4', value: 4, bool:true },
            { display: '5', value: 5, bool:true },
            { display: '6', value: 6, bool:true },
            { display: '7', value: 7, bool:true }
         ];
                $scope.add = function(value){
                $scope.initialSet.push(value);
             $scope.selectedBucket = $filter('bootstrapValues')($scope.initialSet, $scope.bucketEnum);
            }
        });

        app.filter('bootstrapValues', function(){
        return function(initial, baseBucket){
            var result = [];
            for(var i = 0; i < initial.length; i++){
                var flag = false;
                for(var j=1; j<baseBucket.length; j++){ //from 1 or 0.. you call
                    if(initial[i] === baseBucket[j].value){
                        flag = true;
                        baseBucket[j].bool = false;
                        break; // if there are repeated elements
                    }
                } 
            }
            return result;
        };
 });
```

Comment: do you want to disable the select display value, if already contained in `initialSet ` array ?, or you just don't want them in select option?

Comment: I want to hide the value in the select if the value is in the array

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there's an attribute you can set that will hide the element. The solution for you probably then would be to make an array for display values and populate it from data from the second array that you may want to display.

Comment: I don't understand :/ I Have two array, One array init with data and the second with the value that I want to add in my first table. So I init too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to disable the added value in current `select`, then You can achieve this by **disable when** syntax of **angular 1.4+ version**

See this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/s18krb6a/) of your code.(for disable)

and, If you want to delete the added value in current `select` then See this [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3p30750p/) (for delete)